# NavigationService.Navigate not working on my Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to invoke this method **NavigationService.Navigate**

from a class which extends a BaseCommand class (it is a cordova/phonegap plugin) and not a PhoneApplicationPage.

But the framework cannot find it neither **Frame**
How to achieve it and change the page?

I am using wpsilverlight 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Windows platform for 8.1 doesn't use Silverlight but uses WWA. So you would need to reference WinRT and WinMD for your scenario. Let us know more about your application and questions you have with our tools. Thanks!

Comment: what are WWA and WinMD?